# What is the easiest way to find the domain of a composite function ?

Tags: real-analysis

> What is the easiest  way  to find the  domain of a composite function ?

I need the most direct way to find the domain of composite  function  successfully

Comment: That's a pretty short question.  I hope you aren't asking this to finish your homework quicker.

Comment: It depends on the functions that you are dealing with

Comment: Perhaps keeping this question open is justified by the fact that it admits the kind of answer that I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest is based on the definition :

$$x\in D_{g\,\circ\, f}\iff x\in D_f \;\;\land \;\;f (x)\in D_g $$

So, first find $D_f  \; $, then $D_g $ and solve for $x\in D_f $, the condition 
$$f (x)\in D_g . $$

For example

$$x\in D_{\arcsin (x\sqrt {x^2-1})} \iff $$

$$x^2-1\ge 0 \;\;\land -1\leq x\sqrt {x^2-1}\le 1$$

Answer (score 0):

To be in the domain of $x\mapsto f(g(x)),$ a number $x$ must first be in the domain of $g$.

The other thing that is necessary is that $g(x)$ be in the domain of $f.$

Comment: This surely presumes a certain sloppiness in language and presumption of the asker's intent.  This is an answer to "What is the largest domain that would allow the pointwise composite to be defined?", whereas the composite $f \circ g$ would technically not exist if the codomain of $f$ is not a subset of the domain of $g$.  This presumption is evident, for example, when we say that the domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.  Any full answer should make the presumption of interpretation clear.

Comment: @qman : Did you interchange $f$ and $g,$ and actually intend to say $f\circ g$ would not exist if the codomain of $g$ is not a subset of the domain of $f\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @qman : I don't understand what alternative interpretation of the question you have in mind, besides "What is the largest domain that would allow the pointwise composite to be defined?". $\qquad$

Comment: Michael - yes, to your first question.  I guess I have difficulty with the sloppy way we teach maths: for example, "domain" is taken to mean "the largest set, within some implied set (such as $\Bbb{C}$), to which successive application of the functions yields a well-defined value", rather its formal definition.  I remember battling with such fuzziness at school: maths required spending energy considering interpretations and then disambiguation through inference of intent.  My teachers were generally blind to this nondefinitional component of how maths is practised.

Comment: @qman : You can sometimes take the "formal definition" to be implied by the context.

Comment: I don't quite follow, though in this instance "the domain of composite function" sounds like a cue for formal definitions.  An informal construction "a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$" might cue informal usage of words such as "domain" and "composite".  Here, however, it could be a serious question about how maths works formally.  If the asker is not going to put effort into clarifying an underspecified question (clear from the comments), IMO the question does not belong here.

Comment: @qman : I think the poster should do more work before you give him an answer to that more involved question.

Comment: I have no intention of posting an answer at all; I was reacting to the fact that neither the question nor the answer clarified that there might be an issue with interpretation, which I feel is long-term pedagogically counterproductive.  Both interpretations and their associated answers are simple two-liners.

Comment: @qman : The "underspecification" that is relevant here is not of the sort you suggest. It is unreasonable to ask posters to know how to be rigorous in the way you seem to have in mind.

Comment: No, I do not expect rigor from the poster.  Only responsiveness to requests for context and detail, not just to leave it open-ended.  It helps if the answers are on the ball, though.  Anyhow, I think we've digressed (my bad).